# MySQL count return 0 instead of no records

Tags: mysql, sql

I've searched for this answer on Stackoverflow and I haven't been able to get any of the posted solutions to work for me.

I have two tables:

```
builds:
build_id (INT)
status_id (INT)
created (INT)
```

And

```
statuses:
status_id (INT)
name (VARCHAR)
description (VARCHAR)
```

I'd like to have a query that will return the date, the status of the build and the count for that date and status.  If the count is 0 for a particular status I'd like to have it return 0.  For example:

```
+------------+-------+----------+
| date       | count | name     |
+------------+-------+----------+
| 2013-12-05 |     1 | Failed   |
| 2013-12-05 |     2 | Stable   |
| 2013-12-05 |     1 | Unstable |
| 2013-12-06 |     0 | Failed   |
| 2013-12-06 |     1 | Stable   |
| 2013-12-06 |     1 | Unstable |
+------------+-------+----------+
```

I have tried various left join and ifnull combinations in my sql query.  Here is the query that returns the results without the 0 count:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(created, '%Y-%m-%d') as date,
COUNT(statuses.status_id) as count, statuses.name
FROM builds
LEFT JOIN statuses on builds.status_id=statuses.status_id
GROUP BY date, name;
```

This query displays:

```
+------------+-------+----------+
| date       | count | name     |
+------------+-------+----------+
| 2013-12-05 |     1 | Failed   |
| 2013-12-05 |     2 | Stable   |
| 2013-12-05 |     1 | Unstable |
| 2013-12-06 |     2 | Stable   |
| 2013-12-06 |     1 | Unstable |
+------------+-------+----------+
```

Thank you in advance.

For what it's worth the solutions posted here work: [MySQL Group by - Get columns with zero count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528726/mysql-group-by-get-columns-with-zero-count)

EXCEPT that they require the company name in the where clause (the date field in my situation)...I want to get a listing of all the dates in one query.

Comment: What *does* that query show you?

Comment: Did you try RIGHT JOIN insead of LEFT JOIN in this query ?

Comment: Added the results of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making this work by joining in a separate calendar table similar to what was suggested in this post: [SQL left joining multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722801/sql-left-joining-multiple-tables)

Here is the full query:

```
"SELECT 
  allRecords.date,
  allRecords.Name,
  ( SELECT 
      COUNT(statuses.status_id)
    FROM statuses, builds, calendar
    WHERE builds.status_id = statuses.status_id
      AND FROM_UNIXTIME(builds.created, '%Y-%m-%d') = calendar.date
      AND calendar.date = allRecords.date
      AND statuses.name = allRecords.Name
  ) as Count

FROM 
  ( SELECT calendar.date,
      statuses.status_id,
      statuses.name
    FROM
      calendar,
      statuses
    ORDER BY
      calendar.date,
      statuses.name  ) allRecords

LEFT JOIN builds
  ON builds.status_id =  allRecords.status_id

LEFT JOIN statuses
  ON builds.status_id = statuses.status_id

WHERE allRecords.date BETWEEN 
  (SELECT MIN(FROM_UNIXTIME(builds.created, '%Y-%m-%d')) FROM builds) 
AND 
  (SELECT MAX(FROM_UNIXTIME(builds.created, '%Y-%m-%d')) FROM builds)

GROUP BY
  allRecords.date,
  allRecords.Name

ORDER BY 
  allRecords.date,
  CASE allRecords.Name
    WHEN 'Stable' THEN 1
    WHEN 'Unstable' THEN 2
    WHEN 'Failed' THEN 3
  ELSE 100 END";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(created, '%Y-%m-%d') as date,
       COUNT(builds.status_id) as count, 
       statuses.name
FROM builds
RIGHT JOIN statuses on builds.status_id=statuses.status_id
GROUP BY date, name;
```

or maybe:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(created, '%Y-%m-%d') as date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN builds.status_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) as count, 
       statuses.name
FROM builds
RIGHT JOIN statuses on builds.status_id=statuses.status_id
GROUP BY date, name;
```

COUNT( column ) should in theory count only not null values, but who knows ....

Comment: Thank you, but I'm getting the same results with both of these queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try a right join instead:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(created, '%Y-%m-%d') as date,
COUNT(statuses.status_id) as count, statuses.name
FROM builds
RIGHT JOIN statuses on builds.status_id=statuses.status_id
GROUP BY date, name;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm getting the same results with this query as well.

Comment: try grouping by name, date instead.

Comment: Still getting the same results (no records with 0 in the count column).  I've tried various other combinations as well - still keeping at it.  Thanks for your assistance.