# MySQL Group by - Get columns with zero count

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried decrying other answers, no luck, hence asking.

I have one table and few more similar to this for other year 
Here is the table structure

```
--------------------------------
STATUS       | Year | Company Name 
--------------------------------
Certified    | 2010 | Google
Cert-Denied  | 2010 | Google 
Denied       | 2010 | Google
Withdrawn    | 2010 | Google

Denied       | 2010 | Microsoft
Withdrawn    | 2010 | Microsoft
Certified    | 2010 | Apple
Cert-Denied  | 2010 | Apple
----------------------------------
```

When I write a query to list all the companies in an year GROUP BY STATUS, I want to see all the entries corresponding to a count of the status, including the zero count.

If I search on Google I would get something like this

```
Query : Select status, count(*) from table where company like '%Google%' group by status
```

Result :

```
Certified    | 1| 
Cert-Denied  | 1| 
Denied       | 1| 
Withdrawn    | 1|
```

If I run the same for microsoft, I would get

```
Denied       | 1|
Withdrawn    | 1 |
```

The ones with ZERO Count are missing. I want the ones with ZERO Count as well to be dispalyed like below.

```
Certified    | 0| 
Cert-Denied  | 0| 
Denied       | 1| 
Withdrawn    | 1|
```

I have read about joins and stuff, still not clear. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: If this is an ongoing project that you have control over, you should try to normalize the data a bit. With your current structure, I see breaking this into three tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The COUNT is only returning the COUNT for the status that he finds for Microsoft. And those are Denied and Wthdrawn. You have to feed the query all the statuses and COUNT the occurrences of all of them. The ones that don't appear will in the table will be left with 0:

```
SELECT a.STATUS, 
      SUM(CASE 
        WHEN b.STATUS IS NOT NULL
          THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END) AS StatusCount
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT STATUS
  FROM tab1
  ) a
LEFT JOIN tab1 b ON a.STATUS = b.STATUS AND b.CompanyName = 'Microsoft'
GROUP BY a.STATUS;
```

What this does is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT STATUS
FROM tab1
```

This finds all the statuses possible. If you have a reference table with all the possible statuses, even better Use it instead of this query.

Then you do a LEFT JOIN on this table by status and companyName. This way, you will only get a match in STATUS if there is a record on the table. If there is, you add 1 to the SUM, otherwise you Add 0.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7cc3/9)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

A fairly straight forward way is to get all distinct statuses and `LEFT JOIN` with the table to get the counts;

```
SELECT a.status, COUNT(b.status) cnt
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT status FROM Table1) a
LEFT JOIN Table1 b
  ON a.status = b.status
 AND b.`Company name`='Microsoft'
GROUP BY a.status
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c4e9/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can nest a query, and search for when the Count is equal or greater than zero:

`SELECT a.status, a.stat_count 
FROM (SELECT status, count(*) as stat_count 
      FROM table where company like '%Google%' 
      GROUP BY status) a 
WHERE a.stat_count >= 0`