# multi field Group by in mysql with 0 result

Tags: mysql, group-by

let suppose I have the following tables

**Listing Table**

```
`listing` (
  `fact_listing_id`          INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `region_id`                INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at_date_id`       INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id`              INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fact_listing_id`),
  )
```

**Dim Category Table**

```
`dim_category` (
  `category_id`             INT(11)      NOT NULL,
  `category_name`           VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `parent_category_id`      INT(11)      NULL,
  `parent_category_name`    VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`),
)
```

**Dim Region Table**

```
`dim_region` (
  `region_id`   INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `region_name` VARCHAR(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`region_id`)
)
```

**Dim Date Table**

```
`dim_date` (
  `date_id`       INT(11) NOT NULL, -- date_key
  `date`          DATE,
  `month`         INT(11) NULL,
  `day_of_month`  INT(11) NULL,
  `day_of_week`   INT(11) NULL,
  `week_of_month` INT(11) NULL,
  `year`          INT(11) NULL,
  `quarter`       INT(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date_id`)
)
```

and now I want have a query to get count the number of listings  in each category, in each region and each day by grouping on three fields, 'region_id','category_id' and 'date_id'

for one dimension, I mean grouping on one dimension it works correctly with the following query

```
select
  count(fl.fact_listing_id) as Count
, dr.region_id
from fact_listing fl
     right  JOIN  dim_region dr on fl.region_id = dr.region_id
group by
dr.region_id;
```

**BUT** when I try the following query the results aren't as I expecting

```
select
  count(fl.fact_listing_id) as Count
, dr.region_id
, dc.category_id
, fl.created_at_date_id
from fact_listing fl
     right  JOIN  dim_region dr on fl.region_id = dr.region_id
     right  JOIN dim_category dc on fl.category_id = dc.category_id
     right  JOIN dim_date dd on fl.created_at_date_id = dd.date_id
group by
fl.created_at_date_id
,dr.region_id
,dc.category_id;
```

I want the row which has 0-row result comes in output results, in summary, if I have  10 regions, 20 category and 100 days( in date table ) the results should be 10 * 20 * 100 rows.

my question is something like [MySQL Group by - Get columns with zero count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528726/mysql-group-by-get-columns-with-zero-count) **but grouping on multiple fields( columns).**

Comment: You should provide example data (if possible) and expected output..

Comment: "if I have 10 regions, 20 category and 100 days( in date table ) the results should be 10 * 20 * 100 rows." Sounds to me you need to use `CROSS JOIN`s

Comment: @RaymondNijland sorry but my data set is too large and putting some of them here doesn't help.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I've update my question with adding nother question which is similar to mine.

Comment: "if I have 10 regions, 20 category and 100 days( in date table ) the results should be 10 * 20 * 100 rows." Can't you make a more compact version for example using 2 regions, 2 categories and 10 days?

Comment: @RaymondNijland I've said it as an example, I have 1110 region, 180 category, 700 days.